# How to Import Scala Map from Another Scala File

Tags: scala

I'm new to scala and maybe I'm not searching using the right wording but I am basically trying to do the following. I'll write it in python to get the point across.

Say I have a python file called `settings.py`. And within the settings file I Have a dictionary called settings that looked like this:
`settings = {"env" : "prod", "token" : 1234}`

I then have a `main.py` where I import the settings dictionary like so:

```
from settings import settings
```

How would I do this with a scala map that looked like:

```
val settings = Map("env" -> "prod", 
                   "token" -> 1234)
```

Comment: That `setttings` is inside a **class**? an **object**? a **trait**? or it is a worksheet file?

Comment: settings would be in another .scala file. Does it need to be wrapped in a class?

Answer (score 1):

A top-level statement is not valid in **Scala 2**, except in the RELP *(that will change in **Scala 3**)*.

The best way would be to wrap that in an object so you can import it.

```
// Settings.scala
package foo

object Settings {
  final val settings =
    Map(
      "env" -> "prod", 
      "token" -> 1234
    )
}
```

Which you can use like this:

```
// Main.scala
package foo

import Settings.settings

object Main extends App {
  println(settings)
}
```

*Anyways, it seems you are pretty new to Scala and you do not understand basic concepts like packages and scopes. My advice would be to pick any tutorial or course, so you can learn all that*.